# Threads Vs Loaded class in Java profiling

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, profiling

I profiled my Java application using the Visual VM. I need to know about Loaded classes and Threads in here. It always shows 30 Threads running, is it limit in my JVM? Is there any best practice to maintain Thread and Loaded class ratio?
[image]

Comment: There is no such best practice.

Comment: Why do you think you would need more threads?

Comment: There is no "ratio". These numbers are not related.

Comment: @chrylis actually I don't know about this.

Answer (score 1):

The number of threads created by the VM depends on your application. There is no real limit to the number of threads in Java. A simple GUI applicationmay create 10 threads while an application server can create 100+ threads.

The number of classes depends on your application and the libraries used. If you use many libraries and create a huge application then the number of loaded classes could be 10.000+.

Both values are independent and there is no ratio between them.